# Add style to excel file created with xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, spreadsheet, xslt-1.0

I need to indent the text in specific cells.The specific cells are xml elements that have children.

My XML is:

```
<rows>

<row id="FOLDER1">
    <cell image="blank.gif">Folder 1</cell>
    <cell/>
    <cell/>
    <cell/>
    <cell/>
    <cell/>
    <cell/>
    <cell sum="1">$23</cell>
    <row id="FOLDER2">
        <cell image="blank.gif">Folder 2</cell>
        <cell/>
        <cell/>
        <cell/>
        <cell/>
        <cell/>
        <cell/>
        <cell sum="2">$11</cell>
        <row id="FOLDER3">
            <cell image="blank.gif">Folder 3</cell>
            <cell/>
            <cell/>
            <cell/>
            <cell/>
            <cell/>
            <cell/>
            <cell sum="3">$44</cell>
            <row id="pro1">
                <cell image="blank.gif">Product 1</cell>
                <cell>324234</cell>
                <cell>3.00</cell>
                <cell>Kilo</cell>
                <cell>1.00</cell>
                <cell>No</cell>
                <cell>euro 33.33</cell>
                <cell>euro 33.33</cell>
            </row>
            <row id="pro2">
                <cell image="blank.gif">Product 2</cell>
                <cell>4354354</cell>
                <cell>1.00</cell>
                <cell>Kilo</cell>
                <cell >0.50</cell>
                <cell>No</cell>
                <cell>euro 2.53</cell>
                <cell>euro 1.26</cell>
            </row>

        </row>
        <row id="pro3">
            <cell image="blank.gif">Product 3</cell>
            <cell>435436</cell>
            <cell>10.00</cell>
            <cell>Kilo</cell>
            <cell>Yes</cell>
            <cell>euro 0.36</cell>
            <cell>euro 3.60</cell>
        </row>

        <row id="pro4">
            <cell image="blank.gif">Product 4</cell>
            <cell>435435</cell>
            <cell>3.28</cell>
            <cell>Kilo</cell>
            <cell>1.00</cell>
            <cell>No</cell>
            <cell>euro 17.38</cell>
            <cell>euro 17.38</cell>
        </row>
    </row>
</row>
<row id="FOLDER1">
    <cell image="blank.gif">Folder 4</cell>
    <cell/>
    <cell/>
    <cell/>
    <cell/>
    <cell/>
    <cell/>
    <cell sum="1">$23</cell>
</row>
```

My XSLT is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
    xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
    xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
    xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">


  <xsl:param name="header1">Header1</xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="header2">Header2</xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="header3">Header3</xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="header4">Header4</xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="header5">Header5</xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="header6">Header6</xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="header7">Header7</xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="header8">Header8</xsl:param>

  <xsl:template match="rows">

    <Workbook>
      <Styles>
        <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
          <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom" />
          <Borders />
          <Font />
          <Interior />
          <NumberFormat />
          <Protection />
        </Style>
        <Style ss:ID="s21">
          <Font ss:Size="22" ss:Bold="1" />
        </Style>
        <Style ss:ID="columnheaders">
          <Font ss:Size="12" ss:Bold="1" />
        </Style>
        <Style ss:ID="s22">
          <Font ss:Size="14" ss:Bold="1" />
        </Style>
        <Style ss:ID="s23">
          <Font ss:Size="10"  />
        </Style>
        <Style ss:ID="s24">
          <Font ss:Size="10" ss:Bold="1" />
        </Style>
      </Styles>

      <Worksheet ss:Name="data">
        <Table>
          <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="300" />
          <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="95" />
          <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="95" />
          <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="175" />
          <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="186" />
          <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="185" />
          <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="113" />
          <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="133" />


          <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="18">
            <Cell ss:StyleID="columnheaders">
              <Data ss:Type="String">
                <xsl:value-of select="$header1"/>
              </Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell ss:StyleID="columnheaders">
              <Data ss:Type="String">
                <xsl:value-of select="$header2"/>
              </Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell ss:StyleID="columnheaders">
              <Data ss:Type="String">
                <xsl:value-of select="$header3"/>
              </Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell ss:StyleID="columnheaders">
              <Data ss:Type="String">
                <xsl:value-of select="$header4"/>
              </Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell ss:StyleID="columnheaders">
              <Data ss:Type="String">
                <xsl:value-of select="$header5"/>
              </Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell ss:StyleID="columnheaders">
              <Data ss:Type="String">
                <xsl:value-of select="$header6"/>
              </Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell ss:StyleID="columnheaders">
              <Data ss:Type="String">
                <xsl:value-of select="$header7"/>
              </Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell ss:StyleID="columnheaders">
              <Data ss:Type="String">
                <xsl:value-of select="$header8"/>
              </Data>
            </Cell>
          </Row>

          <xsl:apply-templates select="row"/>

        </Table>
      </Worksheet>

    </Workbook>

  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="row">
    <xsl:variable name="rowID">
      <xsl:number level="any" format="1"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="18">
      <xsl:for-each select="cell">
        <xsl:variable name="colID">
          <xsl:number value="position()" format="A"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
          <Data ss:Type="String">
            <xsl:value-of select="translate(.,'?','&#8364;')"/>
          </Data>
        </Cell>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </Row>

    <xsl:apply-templates select="row"/>
  </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My output generated from the transformations:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workbook xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
    <Styles>
        <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
            <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
            <Borders/>
            <Font/>
            <Interior/>
            <NumberFormat/>
            <Protection/>
        </Style>
        <Style ss:ID="s21">
            <Font ss:Size="22" ss:Bold="1"/>
        </Style>
        <Style ss:ID="columnheaders">
            <Font ss:Size="12" ss:Bold="1"/>
        </Style>
        <Style ss:ID="s22">
            <Font ss:Size="14" ss:Bold="1"/>
        </Style>
        <Style ss:ID="s23">
            <Font ss:Size="10"/>
        </Style>
        <Style ss:ID="s24">
            <Font ss:Size="10" ss:Bold="1"/>
        </Style>
    </Styles>
    <Worksheet ss:Name="data">
        <Table>
            <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="300"/>
            <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="95"/>
            <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="95"/>
            <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="175"/>
            <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="186"/>
            <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="185"/>
            <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="113"/>
            <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="133"/>
            <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="18">
                <Cell ss:StyleID="columnheaders">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Header1</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="columnheaders">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Header2</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="columnheaders">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Header3</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="columnheaders">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Header4</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="columnheaders">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Header5</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="columnheaders">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Header6</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="columnheaders">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Header7</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="columnheaders">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Header8</Data>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
            <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="18">
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Folder 1</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String"/>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String"/>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String"/>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String"/>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String"/>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String"/>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">$23</Data>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
            <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="18">
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Folder 2</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String"/>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String"/>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String"/>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String"/>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String"/>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String"/>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">$11</Data>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
            <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="18">
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Folder 3</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String"/>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String"/>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String"/>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String"/>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String"/>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String"/>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">$44</Data>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
            <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="18">
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Product 1</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">324234</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">3.00</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Kilo</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">1.00</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">No</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">euro 33.33</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">euro 33.33</Data>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
            <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="18">
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Product 2</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">4354354</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">1.00</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Kilo</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">0.50</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">No</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">euro 2.53</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">euro 1.26</Data>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
            <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="18">
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Product 3</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">435436</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">10.00</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Kilo</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Yes</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">euro 0.36</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">euro 3.60</Data>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
            <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="18">
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Product 4</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">435435</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">3.28</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Kilo</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">1.00</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">No</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">euro 17.38</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">euro 17.38</Data>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
            <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="18">
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Folder 4</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String"/>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String"/>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String"/>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String"/>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String"/>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String"/>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">$23</Data>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
        </Table>
    </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

And here how it looks like when opened in excel:
[image: screenshot]

I need to indent the cells recursively and also to check if the rows have children if they do i need to make them italic,if not just to leave them unedited.
Example of how it should look like:

```
*Folder1*
   *Folder2*
       *Folder3*
          Product1
          Product2
   Product3
   Product4
 Folder4
```

Here is the xml i should get:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workbook xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
    <Styles>
        <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
            <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
            <Borders/>
            <Font/>
            <Interior/>
            <NumberFormat/>
            <Protection/>
        </Style>
        <Style ss:ID="s21">
            <Font ss:Size="22" ss:Bold="1"/>
        </Style>
        <Style ss:ID="columnheaders">
            <Font ss:Size="12" ss:Bold="1"/>
        </Style>
        <Style ss:ID="s22">
            <Font ss:Size="14" ss:Bold="1"/>
        </Style>
        <Style ss:ID="s23">
            <Font ss:Size="10"/>
        </Style>
        <Style ss:ID="s24">
            <Font ss:Size="10" ss:Bold="1"/>
        </Style>
        <Style ss:ID="parent1">
            <Font ss:Size="10" ss:Italic="1"/>
        </Style>
        <Style ss:ID="parent2">
            <Alignment ss:Indent="1"/>
            <Font ss:Size="10" ss:Italic="1"/>
        </Style>
        <Style ss:ID="parent3">
            <Alignment ss:Indent="2"/>
            <Font ss:Size="10" ss:Italic="1"/>
        </Style>
        <Style ss:ID="children3">
            <Alignment ss:Indent="3"/>
            <Font ss:Size="10"/>
        </Style>
        <Style ss:ID="children2">
            <Alignment ss:Indent="2"/>
            <Font ss:Size="10"/>
        </Style>
    </Styles>
    <Worksheet ss:Name="data">
        <Table>
            <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="300"/>
            <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="95"/>
            <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="95"/>
            <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="175"/>
            <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="186"/>
            <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="185"/>
            <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="113"/>
            <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="133"/>
            <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="18">
                <Cell ss:StyleID="columnheaders">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Header1</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="columnheaders">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Header2</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="columnheaders">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Header3</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="columnheaders">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Header4</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="columnheaders">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Header5</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="columnheaders">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Header6</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="columnheaders">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Header7</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="columnheaders">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Header8</Data>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
            <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="18">
                <Cell ss:StyleID="parent1">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Folder 1</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String"/>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String"/>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String"/>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String"/>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String"/>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String"/>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">$23</Data>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
            <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="18">
                <Cell ss:StyleID="parent2">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Folder 2</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String"/>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String"/>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String"/>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String"/>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String"/>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String"/>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">$11</Data>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
            <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="18">
                <Cell ss:StyleID="parent3">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Folder 3</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String"/>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String"/>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String"/>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String"/>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String"/>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String"/>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">$44</Data>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
            <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="18">
                <Cell ss:StyleID="children3">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Product 1</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">324234</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">3.00</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Kilo</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">1.00</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">No</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">euro 33.33</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">euro 33.33</Data>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
            <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="18">
                <Cell ss:StyleID="children3">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Product 2</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">4354354</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">1.00</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Kilo</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">0.50</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">No</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">euro 2.53</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">euro 1.26</Data>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
            <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="18">
                <Cell ss:StyleID="children2">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Product 3</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">435436</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">10.00</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Kilo</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Yes</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">euro 0.36</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">euro 3.60</Data>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
            <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="18">
                <Cell ss:StyleID="children2">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Product 4</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">435435</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">3.28</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Kilo</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">1.00</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">No</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">euro 17.38</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">euro 17.38</Data>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
            <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="18">
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Folder 4</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String"/>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String"/>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String"/>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String"/>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String"/>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String"/>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">$23</Data>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
        </Table>
    </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

Screenshot using the xml i should get:
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a listing of the expected output as XML?

Comment: I've edited my answer and added the expected xml output.You can open the xml with excel in order to see graphically how it looks like.

Comment: I opened your "expected xml" in Excel 2003, and all the content appeared in the first cell. Unless you are using a different version of Excel, you may want to check your xml for correctness.

Comment: I use Excel 2007 and here it looks fine,i've put screenshot of how is displayed here.

Comment: I just need to find if the row has children and count how many are there so i can apply the styles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the indentation, I would start off by adding a new parameter to hold the size of the indentation you require for each level. In this case, I am using four spaces.

```
<xsl:param name="indentAmount" select="'    '" />
```

Then, within your template that matches the **row** element, you can have a parameter that stores the size of the current identation to use, which will initially default to an empty string (i.e no indentation).

```
<xsl:template match="row">
   <xsl:param name="indentation" select="''" />
```

When you recursively call your row template, you just add on the paramterised indentation amount to the current indentation, to increase it

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="row">
  <xsl:with-param name="indentation" select="concat($indentAmount, $indentation)" />
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

Then, it is simply a case of outputing the indentation parameter for the first cell

```
<Data ss:Type="String">
   <xsl:if test="$colID = 'A'">
      <xsl:value-of select="$indentation" />
   </xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="translate(.,'?','&#8364;')"/>
</Data>
```

For the italics, you can simply define a new style

```
 <Style ss:ID="s23i">
   <Font ss:Size="10" ss:Italic="1" />
 </Style>
```

Then, you can just set the style attribute of the cell depending on whether it has a **row** element as a child

```
<Cell>
   <xsl:attribute name="ss:StyleID">
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="$colID = 'A' and ../row">s23i</xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>s23</xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:attribute>
```

As a side issue, you have the processing instruction `<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>` in your XSLT. This is not the right place for it, as it needs to appear in your output XML, and this won't happen currently. To output this process instruction, you need to do this

```
  <xsl:processing-instruction name="mso-application">
     <xsl:text>progid="Excel.Sheet"</xsl:text>
  </xsl:processing-instruction>
```

Here is the full XSLT in all its glory then....

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
    xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
    xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
    xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">

   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:param name="header1">Header1</xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="header2">Header2</xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="header3">Header3</xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="header4">Header4</xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="header5">Header5</xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="header6">Header6</xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="header7">Header7</xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="header8">Header8</xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="indentAmount" select="'    '" />

  <xsl:template match="rows">
      <xsl:processing-instruction name="mso-application">
         <xsl:text>progid="Excel.Sheet"</xsl:text>
      </xsl:processing-instruction>
    <Workbook>
      <Styles>
        <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
          <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom" />
          <Borders />
          <Font />
          <Interior />
          <NumberFormat />
          <Protection />
        </Style>
        <Style ss:ID="s21">
          <Font ss:Size="22" ss:Bold="1" />
        </Style>
        <Style ss:ID="columnheaders">
          <Font ss:Size="12" ss:Bold="1" />
        </Style>
        <Style ss:ID="s22">
          <Font ss:Size="14" ss:Bold="1" />
        </Style>
        <Style ss:ID="s23">
          <Font ss:Size="10"  />
        </Style>
        <Style ss:ID="s23i">
          <Font ss:Size="10" ss:Italic="1" />
        </Style>
        <Style ss:ID="s24">
          <Font ss:Size="10" ss:Bold="1" />
        </Style>
      </Styles>

      <Worksheet ss:Name="data">
        <Table>
          <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="300" />
          <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="95" />
          <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="95" />
          <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="175" />
          <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="186" />
          <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="185" />
          <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="113" />
          <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="133" />
          <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="18">
            <Cell ss:StyleID="columnheaders">
              <Data ss:Type="String">
                <xsl:value-of select="$header1"/>
              </Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell ss:StyleID="columnheaders">
              <Data ss:Type="String">
                <xsl:value-of select="$header2"/>
              </Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell ss:StyleID="columnheaders">
              <Data ss:Type="String">
                <xsl:value-of select="$header3"/>
              </Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell ss:StyleID="columnheaders">
              <Data ss:Type="String">
                <xsl:value-of select="$header4"/>
              </Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell ss:StyleID="columnheaders">
              <Data ss:Type="String">
                <xsl:value-of select="$header5"/>
              </Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell ss:StyleID="columnheaders">
              <Data ss:Type="String">
                <xsl:value-of select="$header6"/>
              </Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell ss:StyleID="columnheaders">
              <Data ss:Type="String">
                <xsl:value-of select="$header7"/>
              </Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell ss:StyleID="columnheaders">
              <Data ss:Type="String">
                <xsl:value-of select="$header8"/>
              </Data>
            </Cell>
          </Row>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="row"/>
        </Table>
      </Worksheet>
    </Workbook>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="row">
    <xsl:param name="indentation" select="''" />
    <xsl:variable name="rowID">
      <xsl:number level="any" format="1"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="18">
      <xsl:for-each select="cell">
        <xsl:variable name="colID">
          <xsl:number value="position()" format="A"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <Cell>
           <xsl:attribute name="ss:StyleID">
              <xsl:choose>
                 <xsl:when test="$colID = 'A' and ../row">s23i</xsl:when>
                 <xsl:otherwise>s23</xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>
           </xsl:attribute>
          <Data ss:Type="String">
             <xsl:if test="$colID = 'A'">
                <xsl:value-of select="$indentation" />
             </xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="translate(.,'?','&#8364;')"/>
          </Data>
        </Cell>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </Row>

    <xsl:apply-templates select="row">
       <xsl:with-param name="indentation" select="concat($indentAmount, $indentation)" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Great just what i needed,i thought making styles for indent,but this also works.Thanks Tim

Comment: Ah yes. I originally missed the fact you can have specific styling for indentation. Padding with spaces was slightly easier (otherwise you would need separate styles for each level of indentation, and also for whether they were italic or not. In your case this would need 6 separate styles).